# A bug in processing code

Tags: image-processing

Applying the following code to convert from a grayscale image to threshold but the output would be a total black picture any ideas:

```
PImage toThreshhold(PImage sourcePic)
{
    PImage thresh = new PImage(sourcePic.width,sourcePic.height);

    sourcePic.loadPixels(); 
    for(int i = 0; i < sourcePic.width; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<sourcePic.height; j++)
        {
            int pixPosition = i*sourcePic.width +j; 
            if(sourcePic.pixels[pixPosition] > 127)
            {
                sourcePic.pixels[pixPosition] = color(255);
            }
            else
            {
                sourcePic.pixels[pixPosition] = color(0);
            }
        }
    }
    sourcePic.updatePixels();

    return thresh;
}
```

Comment: You should specify the language using a tag. Also, I've had this kind of general problem often when forgetting to convert from floating-point to integer or vice-versa.

Comment: what is the output you're getting, and how is it different from what you are expecting?  post screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

```
int pixPosition = i*t.width +j;
```

is wrong. It should be

```
int pixPosition = i*t.height +j;
```

and you aren't modifying tresh in any way. This should be ok:

```
thresh = sourcePic;
thresh.loadPixels(); 
for(int i = 0; i < t.width; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j<t.height; j++)
    {
        int pixPosition = i*t.height +j; 
        if(thresh.pixels[pixPosition] > 127)
        {
            thresh.pixels[pixPosition] = color(255);
        }
        else
        {
            thresh.pixels[pixPosition] = color(0);
        }
    }
}
thresh.updatePixels();

return thresh;
```

Comment: it still giving the same result ,,,, black picture

Answer (score 0):

What language is this ? C or C++ ? And what are loadPixels() and updatePixels() ?

You probably want `int pixPosition = j*sourcePic.width +i;`

Comment: its processing...  a java based language